# Magento 1.9.0.1 with sample data 1.9.0.0 install did not work

Tags: css, ce-1.9.0.1, installation, sample-data

This looks to just be a simple problem, but I cannot find an answer to it. Here is the site:

http://www.cindyconner.com

Magento 1.9.0.1
Sample Data 1.9.0.0

My server tested OK for the install.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more details as to what you did for testing and what you did to change version?

Comment: Did you install the sample data first and *then* step through the Magento install?

Answer (score 2):

Try 
Go to :

```
http://www.cindyconner.com/index.php/admin and login with your admin details
```

> clearing Magento Cache via System > Cache Management

and

> Re-indexing Data via System > Index Management

Comment: Thank you, but I can't get to any of the back end dashboard either.

Comment: Looks like some files might not have uploaded - I can't get into /skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css (it's failing to load your CSS).

Comment: updated my answer on how you to login admin

Comment: Thanks. I am reloading some of the files now to see if that works. Again, thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Thank you! It was the skin directory that was missing. Have a great day!!!